# How to make a class return a value?

Tags: python, class

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._vector = np.array([x, y, z])
        self._magnitude = np.linalg.norm(self._vector)
        self._direction = self._vector/self._magnitude

    @property
    def magnitude(self) -> float:
        return self._magnitude

    @property
    def direction(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self._direction


vec = Vector(10, 4, 2)
print(vec) # <__main__.Vector object at 0x0000027BECAAFEE0>
print(vec.magnitude) # 10.954451150103322
print(vec.direction) # [0.91287093 0.36514837 0.18257419]
```

When I try to `print(vec)` it returns the allocated memory address and not the value of the array, `which should be [10, 4, 2]`.

NOTE: I don't want to use `__repr__` because in that way I would get a string and I need the actual type to be returned. The one above is just a small example.

Comment: `print` _needs_ a string. You can only print a string. When you print an object of a different type, it is implicitly converted to a string by calling `repr` on it. I'm not sure what you mean by _"I need the actual type to be returned"_

Comment: Also note that your `magnitude` is a `float`, not a `ndarray`.

Comment: `print` just prints to the screen/a file. Why are you printing if you need to use the object? What is your end goal?

Comment: You can't make the class instance morph into a list in certain contexts, but you can make instances of the class callable, in which case you could do `print(vec())` to get what you want.  I think that's the closest you can get.

Comment: I used ```print``` for simplicity. For example, what if I need to do ```new_vec = 2*vec```? then I expect that ```print(new_vec) # [20 8 4]```

Comment: You do that by defining a `__mul__()` method so that multiplication will be distributed to the elements.

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-generic-types for more magic methods you could use.

Comment: Classes *do* return  a value, *an instance of the class*. That is what *classes are for*.

Comment: @TomKarzes but why? Just expose `_vector`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know, what I am looking for is to make it return a private attribute (```_vector``` in this case) rather than its instance. Is it possible to override that?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not saying it's a good idea, just that it seems to be closest to what OP originally asked for.

Comment: @mauro no, you cannot simultaneous be an instance of your class and another thing. And you shouldn't even want that, that would lead to pure madness.

Comment: @mauro so, think about what you are proposing. You want `vec` to evaluate to a `numpy.ndarray`, but simultaneously, you want `vec.magnitude` and `vec.direction` to call the methods you've defined on your `Vector` class. How is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific thing to be printed when you send your class to the `print` function, you need to overload the `__str__` or `__repr__` functions:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self._vector)

def __repr__(self):
    return str(self._vector)
```

You need to use one of these because `print` simply takes the string representation of whatever is sent to it and prints it to the screen. If you're looking for a function that returns `self._vector` as an object that you can then print, then you should write a function to do that:

```
@property
def value(self):
    return tuple(self._vector)
```

After reading the comments, it seems that what you actually want is the ability to modify `self._vector` arithmetically. You can do this by overloading, `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__`, `__div__`:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    result = self._vector + other._vector
    return Vector(result[0], result[1], result[2])

def __sub__(self, other):
    result = self._vector - other._vector
    return Vector(result[0], result[1], result[2])

def __mul__(self, other):
    result = self._vector * other
    return Vector(result[0], result[1], result[2])

def __div__(self, other):
    result = self._vector / other
    return Vector(result[0], result[1], result[2])
```

Implementing these will allow you to do the following:

```
a = Vector(1, 2, 3)
b = Vector(4, 5, 6)
a + b   # [5, 7, 9]
b - a   # [3, 3, 3]
2 * a   # [2, 4, 6]
a / 2   # [0.5, 1, 1.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getter property to return the value since you don't want to use `__repr__`. The same way you used property to return magnitude and direction.

Your code should look like this

```
import numpy as np

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._vector = np.array([x, y, z])
        self._magnitude = np.linalg.norm(self._vector)
        self._direction = self._vector/self._magnitude

    @property
    def vector(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self._vector
      
    @property
    def magnitude(self) -> float:
        return self._magnitude

    @property
    def direction(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self._direction


vec = Vector(10, 4, 2)
print(vec.vector) # [10 4 2]
print(vec.magnitude) # 10.954451150103322
print(vec.direction) # [0.91287093 0.36514837 0.18257419]
```